# Django form with spotipy not updating on Apache2

Tags: python, django, spotipy

I've made a Django website with this form.py to populate a template html with a dropdown list with all my current spotify playlists:

```
from django import forms 
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util


def getplaylists(): 

    #credentials
    CLIENT_ID='xxxxx'
    CLIENT_SECRET='xxxxx'
    USER='xxxxxx'

    # token krijgen
    token = util.oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
    cache_token = token.get_access_token()
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(cache_token)

    # playlists opvragen
    results = sp.user_playlists(USER,limit=50)

    namenlijst = []
    idlijst = []

    for i, item in enumerate(results['items']):
        namenlijst.append(item['name'])
        idlijst.append(item['id'])

    #samenvoegen
    dropdowndata = zip(idlijst, namenlijst)
    #dropdowndata = zip(namenlijst, idlijst)

    return dropdowndata


class SpotiForm(forms.Form):  

    LIJSTEN = getplaylists()
    lijstje = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LIJSTEN, required=True)
```

I'm running two versions of this Django website on my VPS (with exactly the same code):

 A) a version on Apache2 (with mod_wsgi)

 B) a test version ('python ./manage.py runserver x.x.x.x:xxx')

When I add or delete a playlist in Spotify the dropdown list in version A gets updated, but the dropdown list of version B does not. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on Apache - or any proper hosting environment - a process lasts for multiple requests, but anything done at class or module level is only performed once per process.

Dynamic things like this should be done inside methods. In this case, put it in the form's `__init__`:

```
class SpotiForm(forms.Form):  
    lijstje = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpotiForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['lijstje'].choices = getplaylists()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I do not know what methods are, but I'm going to find out... I have so much to learn about Python and I'm loving it :) . Thanks again for your solution!